# Visual Basic write text file adds an extra line feed

Tags: vb.net

I have a visual basic application where I read in an excel spreadsheet and write the contents to a .csv file.  The application works as expected however there appears to be an extra line feed generated at the end of each line.  This is the code I am executing:

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

    Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
    strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
    TextBox1.Visible = True
    Dim fileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()

    Dim sPath As String = StrReverse(fileName) 'reverse the string
    sPath = Mid(sPath, InStr(sPath, "\"), Len(sPath)) 'extract from the first slash
    sPath = StrReverse(sPath) 'reverse it again

    Dim xlsFileFolder As String = sPath
    Dim xlsFileName As String = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
    Dim csvFileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".csv"
    Dim csfFileNameAndPath As String = xlsFileFolder + csvFileName

    If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(xlsFileFolder)
        Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles(xlsFileName)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim workbook As IWorkbook
        Dim worksheet As ISheet
        Dim sheetCount As Integer
        Dim file = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        workbook = New HSSFWorkbook(file)
        sheetCount = workbook.NumberOfSheets
        Dim table As New DataTable
        worksheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0)

        Dim numberOfDataRecords = worksheet.PhysicalNumberOfRows
        Dim numberOfColumns = worksheet.GetRow(0).PhysicalNumberOfCells


        Dim dataRow As Integer = 0
        Dim dataColumn As Integer = 0
        Dim quote As String = """"
        Dim cellData As String = ""

        Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(csfFileNameAndPath)


            For dataRow = 0 To numberOfDataRecords - 1

                Dim csvLine As String = quote
                For dataColumn = 0 To numberOfColumns - 1
                    cellData = worksheet.GetRow(dataRow).GetCell(dataColumn).ToString()
                    cellData = cellData.Replace(quote, "'")
                    csvLine = csvLine + cellData + quote + "," + quote
                Next
                Dim l As Integer = csvLine.Length - 2
                csvLine = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(csvLine, l)
                csvLine = csvLine + vbCr
                writer.WriteLine(csvLine)
            Next

        End Using
        TextBox1.Text = "Done!"
    End If
End Sub
```

This is an image of the selected excel file:
[image]

And this is an image of the resulting .csv file:
[image]

As you can see, there is a blank line being generated after each line of text in the .csv file.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try commenting out the `csvLine = csvLine + vbCr` and see if that works.

Comment: You don't need the `vbCr`, `WriteLine` does a carriage return anyway.

Comment: @laancelot - makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and you should be fine. `csvLine = csvLine + vbCr`